# What options are there for storing Website/Application/Service Settings

Tags: configuration, settings, application-settings

I am looking into solutions for Storing Application/Environment Settings, and Connection Strings.

**Requirements**:

- Security
- Scalability
- Standalone
- Share settings across multiple platforms

I've looked at the following solutions.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx

---

However, none of the above solutions really solve the issue of sharing these settings across multiple websites, applications, and platforms.

It appears i'll be writing a custom solution which isn't a big deal, but only if required.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated, obviously they don't need to be Microsoft solutions.

This also isn't limited by Programming language it would be more beneficial to be a RESTful service wrapper with OAuth for security.